# Lord Hanuman is called as "Pavan-putra", the son of wind. The Vedas say, there are fortynine winds. Which Pawan, helped conceive Lord Hanuman?

Tags: ramayana, bhagavad-gita

Krishna says in B.Gita (chapter #10) among the 49 winds, **"marichi"** is His own opulence.

The Vedic Puranas further relate that Sage Kashyap fathered daityas (demons) from his second wife Diti. However, apart from the daityas, Diti desired to have a son more powerful than Indra (the king of the celestial gods). So she kept her baby in her womb for a year. Indra then used a thunderbolt and split her fetus into many pieces, but it turned into many fetuses. These became the Maruts, or the 49 kinds of winds that flow in the universe, doing tremendous good. The major ones amongst them are Avaha, Pravaha, Nivaha, Purvaha, Udvaha, Samvaha, and Parivaha. **The chief wind, known as Parivaha, also bears the name Marichi**. Shree Krishna states that His **vibhūti (opulence)** manifests in the wind called **“Marichi”.**

Is this **"Marichi"**, the same wind who helped father the divine birth of Lord Hanuman??

Answer (score 2):

According to Madhva Taratamya Lord Hanuman is son of main deity Vayu who belongs Level 3 in Devatha  heirarchy tree (Taratamya Tree) who is the husband bharathi. They are called parashukla thriya (higher bright 3) they Lakshmi,Brahma/Vayu and Saraswathi/Bharathi. Why because they dont have even bit of wrong knowledge of Narayana or his Gunas. Apart from this three all have partial knowledge of Lord Narayana. Whatever 49 Maruts devatha are below 37 Level. execept shrI AhamkArika prANa(9) and Pravaha(11).

Reference

> > http://madhwabrahmanas.blogspot.com/2009/03/devata-taratamya.html

Comment: "Why because they dont have even bit of wrong knowledge of Narayana or his Gunas. Apart from this three all have partial knowledge of Lord Narayana. Whatever 49 Maruts devatha are below 37 Level. execept shrI AhamkArika prANa(9) and Pravaha(11)."

Comment: But Bh.Gita also mentions the opulence of Lord Krishna. The point here is, which is more important, Bh.Gita or a blog.

Comment: Bhagavad gita in vibhuti he says he is tree ashva, he is prahalada he is makaraa crocadile. he is king if you take litterally  every word of gita -> veda-> vedanta(Upanishad) you will end up in quagmirre of contradiction.. that is why we have greate acharya like srimad acharya to decipher the scripture.. If you take hanuman hanuman is never defeated by Vali and Ravana (reference from Ramayana) Vali is incarnation of indra who is well above marut ganas in taratamya tree.. always lower level will have lower power than higher

Comment: Marrichi is lower his son will have less sway over indra not supreme

Comment: "Vali is incarnation of indra who is well above marut ganas in taratamya tree.. always lower level will have lower power than higher –" Lord Hanuman is the divine spirit of Lord Shiva. The wind, "Pavan" only assisted in the conception in the divine birth of Lord Hanuman by transplanting the spirit of Lord Shiva in Mother Anjana's "garbha".